# Knife project error (Bug v2.93.4)

Tags: modeling, error, knife-tool

I've looked through the other posts, none of them helped me.

Keep getting "No other selected objects found to use for projection" when trying to use the 'Knife Project' tool.
Very confused, not sure what am I doing wrong, I am selecting one object and the second one, entering edit mode and searching for knife project, same as I always do, used to work every time.

Adding a Gif to show my process.. [image]

[image]

Thanks,.

Comment: Can you tell me more precisely your steps? Because I did it and it work as intended... It makes what you say only if I don't select one of the planes and that's pretty much what it says. Are you sure you selected both of them?

Comment: @MikoCG, I have added a gif showing the process, selecting cutter then the cut object, moving to cutting angle, searching and applying knife project.
I wonder if there is something wrong with my blender installation - v2.93.4

Comment: Hmm not sure because it works in my 2.92 as I didnt upgrade for 2.93.4 yet

Comment: Huh it doesn't work in 2.93.4, I just tried it, send it as bug to blender devs if you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devs changed knife project for 2.93.4.  I think it's a bug, but here's the new method

- In object mode, select only the object you want to project *to*.
- In edit mode, select the cutter object *using the outliner*.
- project as usual.

Comment: thanks :) just seen that on the dev page, the new way is much more complicated, why would you change that :(  - https://youtu.be/M9EMWYOgmqk,  https://developer.blender.org/T91139